# Can you use AutoHeight rows on row selection

Tags: ag-grid

I am in the process of evaluating the enterprise edition to replace our existing grid solutions.  In our grid we often have a lot of rows, and the data in those rows are often quite long.  For that reason I would like to use the standard row size most of the time (default 28px) to see as many rows as possible initially, but when a user selects the row I want it to expand the row to fit the data vertically. I know how to use the AutoHeight in conjunction with cell-wrap-text to make the cells size, but that applies for the entire grid and I want it to act on a per row basis.

I can get really close by setting the grid to use autoHeight, then force the grid to use the default size unless the row is selected.  Here is my 90% working example..

https://codepen.io/Ternion/pen/arRgOg

```
function fixGridRows(event) {
   event.api.resetRowHeights();
   gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function(rowNode) {
      if(rowNode.selected === false) {
         rowNode.setRowHeight(28);
      }
   });
   gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
}
```

The only issue I have with it is using this approach I lose the default overflow style on the cells that show ellipses when there is more text to show.  I also have to test for performance when I scale up.

I poked around in the source and I see the estimation object used to determine the height the dom requires used to auto size, but that routine is locked into a all columns or nothing approach. I can pull out and maintain my own copy of the estimation object if needed but I hope there is functionality built in that I am missing.

Ideally I would just allow the grid to use the default row height, then using the row selection event, I would either tell the row to auto size just that row or perhaps I could call into the estimate routine and manually set the row height.